# Can't install virtual interpreter in PyCharm in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, python, pycharm, virtualenv

When I try to add virtualenv as an interpreter in PyCharm Community 2018.1.2 in Kubuntu 18.04 I get the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.core'

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Tracking issue for this to be fixed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32099

Comment: Always in linux... No problem on mac/windows, only in linux you always gotta add/fix something to work and get embarrassed when supporting it over the other two...

Comment: Every platform has its own problems.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I had to install it. This was fresh Kubuntu 18.04 install, obviously, without this needed package.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
```

After that I restarted PyCharm and creating virtual project interpreter was successful.

Comment: To bad the question doesn't specify *how* pycharm has been installed. So just for the completness sake: 1. This Pycharm has *probably* been installed with snap. (I use pycharm on several installs on a daily basis and never had this error. Only after testing snap with pycharm on a new 18.04 install) 2. After installing 'python3-disutils'. I received the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'".

Comment: This will not install setup-tools. But `python3-pip` does.

Comment: @MadMike In my case, the issue was a windows install attempting to use the remote SSH interpreter while targeting a raspbian server. Simply installing distutils as shown above was sufficient to get the interpreter going.

Comment: I cannot install `python3-pip`, please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185084/ubuntu-oracle-jdk-issues-but-version-looks-okay

Comment: PyCharm from snap: It got me past that error. Then I got to install setuptools.

Comment: after running this command I get `python3-distutils is already the newest version (3.8.2-1ubuntu1).` but getting the same error, can someone help me.

Answer (score 7):

If @Hrvoje T's answer did not work (it did not work for me) then try this:

Run this command and you should be able to install the packaging tools in Pycharm:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

It's `python3-pip`, not `python-pip` if you are using the Python3 interpreter.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567996/pycharm-python-packaging-tools-not-found

Answer (score 2):

Neither @Hrvoje T and @hyukkyulee worked for me since I had already installed those packages. Uninstalling and reinstalling didn't solve the issue as well.

I just upgraded my system to Ubuntu 19.10 and I noticed that they had upgrade the python interpreter to 3.7. PyCharm however was generating the venv interpreter based to its previous one (python 3.6). By changing the `base interpreter` from `New Interpreter block` I solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, @hyukkyulee solution solved the issue.

It is because, by default, Ubuntu comes with python 2.7 and python 3.x version. 
And if you have installed pip using

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

will install 'pip' in python 2.7 folder.

so you need to specify python3-pip to install pip in python 3 folder along with other util packages.

Comment: I used Kubuntu, not Ubuntu.

Comment: @HrvojeT This will work on any ([KULX]buntu on any plublished version.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with an installation of: 
PyCharm 2019.3.2 (Edu)
Build #PE-193.6494.27, built on February 5, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.5+10-b520.38 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.3.0-7629-generic

Installed on Pop!_OS 19.10 with Python 3.7.2 installed.
I did use Jetbrains Toolbox to install pycharm edu. Jetbrains Toolbox was installed using a script suggested by jetbrain's pycharm download page.

Running: 
`sudo apt install python3-pip`

solved the problem instantly, didn't even have to restart pycharm, just created a new project and no issue setting up the virtual environment.

I did install python-pip after updating to python 3.7.2 before having pychram installed. So same as running python3.7 in a terminal without changing the alias the 3 after python matters.

Answer (score 0):

For me, PyCharm was trying to select Python 3.7 in the project creation wizard, but my base Ubuntu system was using Python 3.8 and `distutils` was installed for Python 3.8.

Solution was to select Python 3.8 as my base interpreter in the project wizard.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Python on Chromebook, Atom -> if you are having issues, then follow the suggestion above:

Running:

`sudo apt install python3-pip`.

Then you can install ipykernel by running:

`python -m ipykernel install --user`

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.