# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.core'

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, python3, pycharm

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 in my PC.
I installed PyCharm. But when I tried to run a simple `print 'hello world'`, it showed a pop-up to install Python Packaging Tools.

When clicked on install, it showed the following error:

Executed command:

> /tmp/tmp9bdigh8apycharm-management/setuptools-39.1.0/setup.py install

Error occured:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.core'

Command Output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/tmp/tmp9bdigh8apycharm-management/setuptools-39.1.0/setup.py", line
>   11, in 
>       import setuptools   File "/tmp/tmp9bdigh8apycharm-management/setuptools-39.1.0/setuptools/**init**.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       import distutils.core ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.core'

Please help me fix this and install the interpreter.

Comment: [Per this already answered Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1319047/302907) you may want to give `sudo apt-get install python-distutils` (Python 2) or `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils` (Python 3) a shot. You may also need to use `sudo apt install python-pip` (Python 2) or `sudo apt install python3-pip` (Python 3) as well.